# I want to fold a package in R but I can't get some meta data

Tags: r

I'm a beginner to R programming.

I try to fold a R package (published by a department in my company) by R studio (to modify some function's code that I usually use).

In the function script that I fold(by F2-key), there is a code which contains what I can't find:

```
meta_table <- get("meta_table")
```

The variable(?) `meta_table` is not defined before.

In the library directory, I can't find the R script file containing the functions I use (But I can reach the function code by F2-key).

On the other hand, there are some .rds/.rdb/.rdx files in the directory, but I can't find any object like "meta_table".

I'd like to find the object: meta_table. But I can't understand this situation that I can't find any function code.

Can you explain what I faced?

Comment: Perhaps it is stored as internal data object, try `package_name:::meta_table`